# Is there any way that I can cancel UK visa Ban?

Tags: visas, uk, visa-refusals, jordan

I am a Jordanian citizen and I applied for UK visa C for me and my husband to visit my daughter who has a temporary residency in UK.

After applying for UK-Visa, my husband got his visa and I got 10 years ban, the reason being that I forgot to mention that I was earlier refused Visa on Jan. 2016.

Should I re-apply or is there any other alternative to get the ban revoked?
please note that omeone ales filled my application and he just answered no and i didn't mentioned because i already had two visas before

Comment: If you need to see your daughter as soon as possible, have her fly to you - because any option for removing a ban is going to take years and more money than flying your daughter first class to anywhere in the world on a return ticket.

Comment: It's a stupid rule because nobody can be expected to have the intent to decieve UK immigration about a previous refusal knowing full well that they have comprehensive databases. Nothing much you can do about it though, unless you plan to undertake a very expensive judicial review by claiming that this was an innocent mistake.

Comment: You _forgot_ you were denied just last year?

Comment: someone ales filled my application and he just answered no and i didn't mentioned because i already had two visas before

Comment: That's not much better. If you sign an application someone else prepared for you _without checking for yourself that the answers they filled in are correct_, then the UK authorities are entirely correct in concluding they can't trust papers you sign.

Answer (score 6):

> Should I re-apply or is there any other alternative to get the ban
>   revoked?

Neither. If you reapply you will simply be refused. If you appeal the ban you will simply be spending a lot of money for a shot at a positive outcome with a probability perhaps no greater than winning the lottery. Of course if you're uber wealthy and that amount is pocket change to you, go ahead.

The best recommendation is serve out your ban and use the appeal money to fly your daughter home for visits when you miss her.